# Solutions for handling large-scale climate dataset in R

Tags: r, raster, netcdf, chunks

I am analyzing ERA5 climate data spanning from 1950 to 2023, covering 73 years.
The dataset has a daily temporal resolution and a spatial resolution of 0.25° (1440 x 720).

Each yearly data is stored in a NetCDF file, containing approximately 365 layers.

Attempting to combine these into a single stack results in around 27000 layers, which is overwhelming for my computer, and even the workplace cluster struggles with this volume.

As I'm new to handling large-scale datasets, I'm seeking advice on best practices and effective solutions for managing and processing this type of data.

Note: I have a preference for working with dataframes over NetCDF files as I will perform time series analysis.

Note 2: different types of analysis will be performed in the future. It's very wide: from simple statistics, to indices computations etc. On a grid cell level.

Note 3: I have heard of processing the data in smaller chunks. Is there a good package to do so in R?

Comment: You mention a spatial resolution, but what is the spatial extent? In other words, how many rows and columns for each file?

Comment: What kind of analysis do you need to do on the data? Since you have hourly data, I presume it is something like daily sums / maximum / minimum, etc. Which variables are you working with? Do you need to combine different variables to produce a result? Please add a few lines to your post describing what analyses you want to undertake.

Comment: Daily data -> monthly statistics, but otherwise same comment as above

Comment: Hi Patrick, as stated in the post is climatic variables. For the analysis it's large. Simple to more complex ones. We are still in the exploring phase.  Yes at some point I will need to combine them (when applying a statistical model).

Comment: As stated the question is a little too vague. It would help if you clarified *what* kind of analysis you are doing. Right now you are just asking "I'm working with a big set of netCDF data, and need help". You won't get a better answer than googling "netcdf analysis using R" unless you give us a specific problem you are trying to solve

Comment: Well, I thought that before I dive into analyzing the data, I should find a way to establish a systematic way to organize and pre-process the data that could significantly simplify any subsequent analysis. So far, I am handling precipitation Prec and PET data to calculate a cumulative water deficit for each grid cell, followed by identifying the maximum deficit values annually, then conducting an extreme value analysis. But I would do other type of analysis in the future.

Comment: As I said, your question needs to be less vague. "establish a systematic way to organize and pre-process" isn't overly helpful. All anyone can really say here is "check out the stars package" or something to that effect. Also, ensure you are telling us about coding problems, not scientific methdology problems. I don't think anyone reading this will know what "cumulative water deficit" is.

Comment: Unfortunately, I still haven't found a way to do this in R. Currently, when I analyse files >10 GB I always use xarray + dask in Python...

Answer (score 0):

You have global coverage of ERA5 data over 73 years, giving you `1440 * 720 * 73 * 365.2425 = 27.6 billion` data points *for each variable* (like temperature, or precipitation). No computer system will process that without chunking.

First of all, forget about working with `data.frame`s on the whole data set. First you need to process it down to a reasonable size and only then can you use a `data.frame` for further analysis (if you really need it).

Secondly, ERA5 data uses the `gregorian` or `standard` calendar. That means you can use the standard `Date` class, for instance to make factors with which to process the data. However, since ERA5 data conforms to the CF Metadata Conventions you are better off with [package CFtime](https://cran.r-project.org/package=CFtime) which gives you better control over the time series.

**Sample by location**

An obvious option to break down the data set is to sample the time series by location, pixel by pixel. This is a bad choice, however, because your data is spread over 73 files and the storage organization inside each file makes this a *very* slow option (data is scattered all over each file). I/O nightmare, don't even consider it.

**Temporal slice**

Your best bet is to process each file individually and then assemble the yearly output into a data object over the entire time series. If you go from daily data to monthly statistics, you'll have about 900 million data points *per statistic* (e.g. monthly maximum T, monthly minimum T). Still very significant, but doable on a good computer. That would look somewhat like this:

```r
# Attach necessary packages
library(ncdf4)
library(CFtime)
library(abind)

# Get a list of your 73 ERA5 files
lf <- list.files("~/your/path/to/ERA5", "\\.nc$", full.names = TRUE)

# Open the files sequentially and process
mon <- lapply(lf, function(fn) {
  # Open the file and create a CFtime object
  nc <- nc_open(fn)
  cf <- CFtime(nc$dim$time$units, nc$dim$time$calendar, nc$dim$time$vals)

  # Create a factor to make monthly statistics
  fac <- CFfactor(cf, "month")

  # Read and process the data, here the monthly maximum T
  data <- ncvar_get(nc, "t2m")
  aperm(apply(data, 1:2, tapply, fac, max), c(2, 3, 1))
  dimnames(data) <- list(as.vector(nc$dim$longitude$vals),
                         as.vector(nc$dim$latitude$vals),
                         levels(fac))
  nc_close(nc)
  data
}

# `mon` is a list with 73 elements, each with 12 layers of monthly max T
# Now put them all into 1 object
all_mon <- abind(mon, along = 3)
```

That still gives you a very large object but at least it'll be manageable. If you want different statistics you can write your own functions and then call that `aperm(apply(data, 1:2, tapply, fac, <<<here>>>), c(2, 3, 1))`.

Comment: Thank you very much Patrick, the only thing is that we will work on daily/weekly data. Not monthly. So if I understand your code, no matter the function I would like to apply on my files, I will have to process each yearly file this way ?

Comment: Yes, this is the basic approach to processing data in smaller chunks. If you stay at the daily resolution then your data set will never reduce so every parameter you derive will have a total size of 50GB - 100GB. You are then probably better off storing the derived parameters per year, to keep the files manageable. Weeks have additional complications of definition (start on Monday or Sunday? which is week 1 in the year?) and they straddle year boundaries so I'd stay clear if you can.

Comment: What about creating data cubes with defined dividing grid coordinates ?

Comment: Yes, you could easily implement your own data cubes by dividing up the lon-lat plane into, say, 10 x 10 degree tiles of all data per year. That would then become a mix of temporal slicing and sampling by location: I/O will be less optimal but on the CPU things may be better due to less RAM load.

Comment: Do you recommend a way to be able to do it on nc files and transform them into raster stack cubes ?